# Laravel new command error

Tags: laravel

I did the following commands:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

and

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

But when I try to do:

```
laravel new blog
```

I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: output in C:\Users\****\AooDara\Roaming\Composer\vendor\laravel\installer\src\NewCommand.php on line 55
    Fatal error: Call to a member function writeln() on null in C:\Users\****\AooDara\Roaming\Composer\vendor\laravel\installer\src\NewCommand.php on line 55
```

Any idea of what went wrong?

Comment: Your error shows "AooDara"; does your path AppData or AooDara?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you already have a directory called 'blog' in your application directory. Try creating a laravel app with different name or delete / rename existing 'blog' directory and try again.

for example `laravel new helloapp`.

However, I think the error showing at the console is a bug of laravel new command. I could see the error at the console when I tried to create a app with same name again from same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The error  not exists now. Try creating other application.